# Instance of abstract class in Kotlin and calling abstract function without overriding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, abstract-class, abstract

I am doing this google codelab **android-room-with-a-view-kotlin**. This is the link to [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin). At the 8th step when creating room database they have used this code

```
// Annotates class to be a Room Database with a table (entity) of the Word class
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Word::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class WordRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

   abstract fun wordDao(): WordDao

   companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time. 
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): WordRoomDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        WordRoomDatabase::class.java, 
                        "word_database"
                    ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I want to ask why there is no error in these 2 lines (val exam & val dao) where I create an instance of this abstract class (in class A) and then call its abstract `function(getNoteDao)` without overriding it.

```
class A{

val exam : WordRoomDatabase = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application) 
val dao = exam.getWordDao()
}
```

Since we know we need to override the `abstract` `function` and can not directly call it but what's happening there. why is there no error

Comment: I believe the overriding classes are automatically generated at compile time. As per the documentation "The class marked with @Dao should either be an interface or an abstract class. At compile time, Room will generate an implementation of this class when it is referenced by a Database". Something similar should also be happening for the abstract database class also. Doc link: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Dao , Further reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029450/why-does-a-dao-have-to-be-an-interface-or-abstract-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no error on the `exam` line because `getDataBase` is a "companion" object, or if you're from the Java world, it means it's a "static" function within the abstract class. This means

- a function within a companion object (or again, a static function) belongs the the CLASS, not the the INSTANCE of the class
- you CAN NOT call a static/companion object function on the instance of the class, so notice when you call "WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase..." there are no parenthesis at the end of "WordRoomDatabase". You didn't need to create an instance of it in order to call the `getDatabase` function

There is no error in line 2 is a little trickier to spot.
Inside of `getDatabase()` you are `Room.dataBaseBuilder(...)` and passing in the abstract class. Inside of that builder, android actually creates the instance of your abstract `WordRoomDatabase`. class and overrides your abstract `wordDao` function

If you're using AndroidStudio, build your code. After it's done there will be a little green arrow pointing down on the column next to `WordRoomDatabase`. If you click on it, you'll be able to see the class that Room generated that overrides your abstract function

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any error because implementation of those abstract classes is generated automatically by `kapt` at compile time. If you look closly at your `build.gradle` file, then you will see that it contains a dependency in the form

```
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:X.X.X'
```

Here `kapt` stands for *kotlin annotation processing tool*, which processes all your Room classes marked with certain annotations such as `@Database` or `@Dao` and generates their implementations. For example, I defined following @Dao interface

```
@Dao
interface WordDao {
    @Insert
    fun insert(word: Word)
}
```

And `kapt` generated following implementation of this class

```
public final class WordDao_Impl implements WordDao {
  private final RoomDatabase __db;

  private final EntityInsertionAdapter<Word> __insertionAdapterOfWord;

  public WordDao_Impl(RoomDatabase __db) {
    this.__db = __db;
    this.__insertionAdapterOfWord = new EntityInsertionAdapter<Word>(__db) {
      @Override
      public String createQuery() {
        return "INSERT OR ABORT INTO `Word` (`someId`) VALUES (?)";
      }

      @Override
      public void bind(SupportSQLiteStatement stmt, Word value) {
        stmt.bindLong(1, value.getSomeId());
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public void insert(final Word word) {
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      __insertionAdapterOfWord.insert(word);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
}
```

Same goes for `WordRoomDatabase`, its implementation is also generated automatically. if you want to look at these classes you can always find them at `\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\yourpackage`, they are marked with _Impl suffix.